# How to vectorize words?

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, nlp

From Keras's documentation:

> The main input will receive the headline, as a sequence of integers (each integer encodes a word). The integers will be between 1
>   and 10,000 (a vocabulary of 10,000 words) and the sequences will be
>   100 words long.

Here the way to encode words seem to be simply using word's index in the constructed vocabulary to represent the word. If there are 'n' words in the training data, then the integer *i* to vectorization would be from [0, n-1].

But in the scikit-learn's CountVectorizer:

> This implementation produces a sparse representation of the counts
>   using scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.

Is there any connection between these two ways of vectorizations of words? Is the count vector representation would be more effective than index based vectorization? The CountVectorizer takes into account of the word frequency.

Answer (score 0):

These are two quite different things. Keras and its indices and embeddings are meant for deep learning, scikit-learn and its `CountVectorizer` come from the classical machine learning.

In Keras (or deep learning frameworks in general), words are usually represented by integer indices. The indices then serve as keys in an embedding matrix to pick up the corresponding word embedding to be used in a neural network. In this case, all vectors are dense because neural networks work with dense continuous representations.

[`CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) in scikit-learn is designed for representing sentences or documents (not realy isolated words). Given a training corpus, it creates a vocabulary of the words occurring in the corpus (using the `fit` method). Then, a sentence or a document is represented as a vector of frequencies of the words that occurred in it (when calling the `transform` method). Because most of the vocabulary does not appear in a single document, many values are zeros and therefore make sense to use a sparse vector.

Such representation mostly makes sense for traditional machine learning. With deep learning you would instead use embeddings, average them, and RNN/CNN over them, or whatever.